# Bootstrap glypicons search displaying as diamond sign

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have been search for couple of hours now and couldn't fix this issue. Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this issue regarding glypicons search? Instead of showing the search icon i can only see diamond and a friend can only see a strange sign like unicode symbol. I checked in my css/bootstrap and I can see my font there. I looked in my console and can see content: ""; tried to enter "\e003" manually but it is converted into the diamond symbol automatically. My site is [click](http://sensationaltibet.com)

Thank you.

Comment: Just a link to your site is too broad. Can you create a jsfiddle or something like that with your problem? (And if you do that you'll probably find out what the problem is.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your fonts are missing (glyphicons).

This is the directory they need to be uploaded to within your theme directory: `/assets/css/bootstrap/`